# High quality images in generated PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I have an application that generates some drawings (lineshapes and picture boxes).

During runtime I would like the user to be able to save whatever is on the form (scrollable) to a PDF file (through cutepdf for example).  I know how to do this with the `printtofile` method, but the problem is with poor quality of the PDF file, when I zoom in I can clearly see the pixels.  Is there anyway to improve the quality of the image in PDF file?
I would like to do that through code in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the DPI Setting in CutePDF Writer Advanced Options (Print Preferences -> Paper/Quality -> Advanced.)

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. Anyone?